# Double-clicking a window’s top or bottom border doesn’t maximize the window’s height any longer

Tags: windows-7, double-click

Double-clicking a window’s top or bottom border to maximize the window’s height is a feature of Windows 7 not commonly known even by long-term or superusers of Windows. Nevertheless it's extremly helpful. In case of directory selection dialogs the OK button of which resides below the bottom of the screen, for instance.

Is there any software that’s known to interfere with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samsung MultiScreen (v3.0.23) that has been shipped with my latest monitors is the culprit:

> *MultiScreen is an available add-on software for Samsung monitors and is in no way necessary for your monitor to function.
>
>   -- [http://www.samsung.com/ph/support/skp/faq/789480](http://www.samsung.com/ph/support/skp/faq/789480_)*

I de-installed it and the maximize-height-on-double-clicking-top-or-bottom-border feature works again.

Comment: Be sure to mark your own answer as the correct one, since you found it yourself.

Comment: @WesSayeed Thanks. I tried this already but SU didn't let me, yet: _„You can accept your own answer in two days“_